# Most Compact Secure Post-Quantum Signatures and Public Keys?

Tags: public-key, signature, post-quantum-cryptography

Which post-quantum public key and signature system includes the most compact reusable keypairs?  E.g. a private key which produces practically unlimited signatures without losing the security provided initially like RSA as opposed to something like hash-based Merkle tree driven signatures with a limited number of uses?

Comment: Modern hash-based signature schemes are practically unlimited.  However, they were never contenders for most compact signatures or public keys.

Comment: What are some of them?

Comment: https://sphincs.cr.yp.to/

Comment: I was asking for a signature system which was the most compact.  41KB per signature is enormous.

Comment: I do believe I warned you up front that they were never contenders for most compact signatures.

Comment: Even so, the Lamport signature I alluded to itself only comes in at 24KB for the public key and signature combined, which is much less than the 42KB for signature and public key combinations of the SPHINCS algorithm.  I'm looking for the most compact, not the first thing to pop up in a google search.

Comment: What do you want a post-quantum signature scheme for?  Quantum cryptanalysis is still a long way off, and public verification keys can usually be given short expiration times so that it doesn't matter if a quantum computer can forge them years from now.  But it does matter if a quantum computer can retroactively decrypt messages that were exchanged years ago, so that's where most of the pqcrypto work has been focused.  (P.S.  I assure you I don't mention things just because they're the first Google hit!  SPHINCS is actually _useful_, unlike Lamport _one-time_ signatures.)

Comment: Even if quantum computers aimed at breaking cryptographic keys are a decade off (which is a pretty absurd estimate imo given how rapidly the technology is developing, even just following moore's law we're looking at 6 years max before they break RSA,) there's zero reason to design a new system around something you know will be worthless.  The proper answer to a technical question is never to ask what the purpose is, the question stands independently of the purpose, especially on a site like Stack Exchange where it will come up in future searches.

Comment: If you look closely, you might see that I didn't actually post an _answer_ to your question.  I asked a clarification question that might help guide the pseudonymous strangers volunteering free advice here to a better solution to the problem you're really trying to solve.  None of the post-quantum signature proposals are really mature yet.  The United States NIST's call for proposals for pqcrypto schemes ended _two weeks ago_; there will be years of cryptanalysis before any are ready for confident widespread deployment and standardization.  But expiration dates on Ed25519 keys work now.

Comment: For clarification, I'm aiming for the smallest possible public key and signature.  If some abominably large private key is needed such a Merkle tree that's more or less OK, but the publicly-visible components have to be as small as can be.  A single use algorithm could work in this application but in that instance the combined public key and signature should be as small as possible.  I might be able to get away with a bit more wiggle room on the size of the public key if it supports a large number of uses (more or less the size divided by the signature size with a small signature.)

Comment: For small signatures _and_ small verification keys, your current best bet is probably some lattice-based signature scheme, or maybe multivariate quadratics—but like I said, the field is not mature, and so there's no good concrete proposal I can confidently send you toward.  Check back in a couple years and the story may be different from the NIST pqcrypto competition.  (For just small signatures, pretty much nothing will beat the code-based CFS, but the public keys are huge.)

Comment: If you are just worried about Moore use ECDSA, I don't even know why would anyone use RSA for anything anymore unless it's legacy.

Comment: @dingrite ECDSA is vulnerable to Shor's algorithm on quantum computers.  Once we hit about 1k qubits all that goes away, and qubits have been holding to moore's law pretty well.  In 6 years we'll exceed 1,000 qubits.  Granted it will only be governments and large corporations with them in 6 years time (most likely,) but does it really matter who the potential bad actor is?

Comment: @CoryG: actually, number of QBits isn't the only thing that matters.  At the very least, you need to perform the computations accurately (which means Quantum Error Correction).  No one has been able to implement that yet; that's another hurdle that will need to be overcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you have to say bye to the assumption that you get something like RSA or even ECDSA. Sizes for post-quantum candidates are larger than for classical schemes. Period. There exist schemes with small public keys *or* signatures but never both. The point is that you can often shift information around between public key and signature but the sum remains the same or gets even worse.

Generally, you got three areas that you can pick from: Hash-based, lattice-based, or multi-variate signatures. Code-based and isogeny-based do not really have practical proposals, yet. Each of these areas has its advantages and disadvantages.

Hash-based gives you the most reliable security guarantees, small public keys and moderate size signatures. For small, fast signatures you require to maintain a state (XMSS / LM-HSS), for stateless schemes (SPHINCS, SPHINCS+, Gravity-SPHINCS) signatures get to the order of 10th of kilobytes.

Lattice-based crypto currently provides you with the best sizes. If the current parameters turn out to be secure you can get away with 2.5 kilobyte signatures and 1.5 kilobyte public keys (Dilithium). However, the cryptanalysis of lattice problems is still on the move. It would not be totally surprising if someone finds an algorithm that is an order of magnitude faster than current attacks (this does not mean that the schemes would be broken but that parameters would have to be adjusted).

Finally, for MQ or multivariate signatures you got two choices: You can go with schemes like UOV or Rainbow (careful: patents) which offer extremely  short signatures but somewhat large public keys (I do not know exact numbers  as all I found are numbers for classical attacks and 80bit security...). If you further add cyclic structure to the keys, public key sizes go down. However, these constructions are heuristic and we only know that they were not yet broken with known attacks. Especially, their security is not only linked to the MQ-problem but also to far less understood problems like IP and MinRank. Alternatively, you can go with something like MQDSS which has a security reduction from MQ. However, then you are at slightly larger sizes than SPHINCS.

Comment: Is there a fundamental reason why post-quantum crypto needs large signatures and/or public keys?

Comment: In general because it uses problems that are closely related to NP-Complete problems which have a huge description size. As the problem instance has to be described either in the public key or in the signature, at least one of them has to be large. However, it is not clear that this is the only way to build post-quantum crypto. Hash-based are an exception for example (with big signatures for other reasons...) but that is why PQ-signatures are currently large

Comment: `First of all, you have to say bye to the assumption that you get something like RSA or even ECDSA.` Is that guaranteed to always be the case?

Comment: I am not aware of a proof that this always has to be the case. However, overcoming the issue requires new ideas that are significantly different from how we build signatures today for the previously mentioned reasons. This is also reflected by the new submissions to NISTs onramp. All unbroken proposals have large signatures or keys for the above reasons.